# How to send a image to a client from my HTTP Server?

Tags: c++, http

I am building a small http server. I am able to send html,css,xml files to the client over HTTP. But I am not able to send image files-.jpg,.png.gif. How do I send it so the browser is able to display the image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send it just like any other (binary-data) file, with the correct Content-Type and Content-Length headers.

Content-Type for:

- JPEG: image/jpeg
- PNG: image/png
- GIF: image/gif

Comment: I have set the Content-Type: image/jpeg  and I am sending it as I send a regular text file using fgets.Still doesn't work.

Comment: @ag07: Don't use fgets. It's meant for text -- images are binary files, and may contain legitimate null bytes and newlines partway through. Use something else, like iostream's ifstream with the ios::binary flag

Comment: Thanks Cameron,I am trying it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Cameron.I was stuck with this for the whole day.I should have used some common sense :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably should set correctly the [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) type of your image.